# Removing the first 16 bytes from a byte array

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, how do I take a byte[] array and remove the first 16 bytes from the array? I know I might have to do this by copying the array into a new array. Any examples or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

See `Arrays` class in the [Java library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-):

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to)
```

`from` is inclusive, whereas `to` is exclusive. Both are zero based indices, so to remove the first 16 bytes do

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(original, 16, original.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] a;

...

if(a.length > 1) {
    byte[] newA = new byte[a.length-2];
    for(int i = 2; i < a.length; ++i)
        newA[i-2]=a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void remove(byte[] b)
{
    for(i=16;i<b.length;i++)
    {
        a[i-16]=b[i];
        Process... arrays
    }
}
```

Comment: @Machavity I thought there would be no better explanation if u keep track of 'i' value. 'a' is a new array out of existing array 'b'. when u want to eliminate the first 16 elements, u start writing the elements of new array from that position (i=16) and a[i-16] is the first byte of new array, so copy till the last value of the old byte array.

Answer (score 0):

`System.arraycopy()` also can do that:

```
public static byte[] truncate(byte[] bytes, int srcPos, int newLength) {
    if (bytes.length < newLength) {
        return bytes;
    } else {
        byte[] truncated = new byte[newLength];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, srcPos, truncated, 0, newLength);
        return truncated;
    }
}
```